# Write a function or count double letters

Tags: python, function, double

I am new to programming and have just learned to basics of strings, slicing and joining. My first assignment is to create a function that takes a set of strings and returns the count of double letters. I am working in python and have been struggling to figure this out.

```
def twin(words):
    pairs = 0
    for i in range(len(words)-1):
        if words[i] == words[i+1]:
            pairs = pairs +1
        return words
```

This is what I’ve come up with so far

Comment: What is the question?  Please provide 1) sample data, and 2) what you have tried / researched so far, and 3) where it’s giving you trouble.

Comment: What do you mean by "double letters"?

Comment: Think about what tools you'll need: You need to go through all letters, of all strings. So we'll need to loop over 1) the number of strings, and 2) the number of letters. Next you'll need to track *what letter has just past*, in order to compare it with the letter we are *on*. Finally, we need another variable to track how many double letters we have.

Comment: I mean double letters as in a repeated character, so if i entered the string ‘I like to go swimming’  it would return the count of double letter which in this case would by mm

Comment: def twin(words):
    pairs = 0
    for i in range(len(words)-1):
        if words[i] == words[i+1]:
            pairs = pairs +1
        return words (this is what I have so far but it does not work)

Comment: @KatieScott in your example 'I like to go swimming', why is it 'mm' not 'ii' since i is also repeated twice. Or does order matter?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi the function needs to count double letters that are next to each other, so words like ‘look book better’ does that make sense?

Comment: @KatieScott believe so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're only taking double letters that are back to back into count, then:

```
def twin(sentence):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(sentence) - 1):
        if sentence[i] == sentence[i+1]:
            counter += 1
    return counter


print(twin('Look book better'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I’m glad I was closer than I thought. Can you explain “counter += 1” and why the + and = have no space between them

Comment: @KatieScott Np. *Actually* you had it right the whole time, you just had to return ```pairs``` *after* the for loop. And the ```counter += 1``` is just a shorthand notation for ```counter = counter + 1```.